# Step-by step form showing end results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have this Step-by step form, and at some point I have a simple calculus.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                // Calculate section 08
                $("#txAssets,#txLiabilities").keyup(function (event) {
                    var assets = $("#txAssets").val();
                    var liabilities = $("#txLiabilities").val();
                    var netEquity = assets - liabilities;
                    $("#txNetEquity").val(netEquity);

                });
```

How can I reuse **netEquity** variable in the last step of the form?
I try this:

**`<div id="rsEquity" class="results" onload="">Equity:<b> ?????? </b></div>`**

```
<script>
$("#rsEquity").text("Equity:" + netEquity );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window scoped variable like this:

```
window.netEquity = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
                // Calculate section 08
                $("#txAssets,#txLiabilities").keyup(function (event) {
                    var assets = $("#txAssets").val();
                    var liabilities = $("#txLiabilities").val();
                    netEquity = assets - liabilities;
                    $("#txNetEquity").val(netEquity);
                });
```

Html:

```
<div class="results" onload="">Equity: <span id="rsEquity"></span></div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
$("#rsEquity").html("Equity:" + netEquity);
</script>
```

Comment: Somehow it was not working but when I put the 
$("#rsEquity").html("Equity:" + netEquity);
inside the function it self it work.